# Amazon EC2 instance revert to the state in which it was created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Is it possible to revert the AWS EC2 instance to the state at which it was created? If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't revert a running instance back to the state it was when it was first spun up, but you can terminate the instance and spin up a new one in its place - this is assuming that 'state which it was created' is one of the AMI's available to you in AWS.

If you have a custom configuration that you would occasionally like to revert to (i.e. with your custom settings, data, software installed on it), the way to do that is spin up an instance - get it configured exactly the way you want it to be and then save the running instance as a private AMI - then whenever you want to revert to that state, delete your running instance and create a new one using your custom 'base' AMI.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-create-custom-ami.html